# Running systemd unit directly after local-fs.target and before basic.target

Tags: systemd

I am creating an embedded system. The embedded system mounts a partition. Directly after mounting the partition, I need to prep an encrypted folder (encfs). I need this to run before any other `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target`

Here is my unit file, which works by it's self.

```
[Unit]
Description=Mx Encrypted Folder

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mxmountencrypted
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/mxunmountencrypted
```

This unit file has no dependencies defined, currently.

Again, I need:

1. To run this directly after mounting file systems (`local-fs.target`)
2. Before any `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target`, where must of the services that depend on it will be ran.
3. It must stop fully before stopping `local-fs.target`, since there will be a nested mount that needs to be unmounted before systemd can unmount the partition.

I looked into using the `systemd.mount` item, but it doesn't support `encfs`.

Comment: can't you use `Before=local-fs.target` + `RequiresMountsFor=/encfs/source/drectory` ?

Comment: systemd.mount should "support" encfs no worse than `fstab` does btw (boot-time handling of the latter is implemented directly in terms of the former).